# transform data frame string variable names

Tags: r, get, transform, dataframe, plyr

I have a data frame that contains dates and id's.  I need to add multiple columns to this data frame based on each date. I use `ddply` to do this as follows:

`ddply(df, "dt", transform, new_column1 = myfun(column_name_1))`

However,I have a bunch of column names and would like to add multiple new columns.  Is there a way that I can pass a string to transform instead of new_column1? For example I tried:

`ddply(df, "dt", transform, get("some_column_name")=myfun(column_name_1))`

but this does not work.  Additionally, if I pass the `column_name_1` to myfun as a string, can I just use `get("column_name_1")` within `myfun` to refer to the column?

**UPDATE:**
NOT SURE HOW TO FORMAT THIS BETTER

```
input:
id    date    val
id1   d1      1
id2   d1      2
id3   d1      3
id4   d1      4
id1   d2      10
id2   d2      20
id3   d2      30
id4   d2      40
```

out (for 2 buckets for example)

```
id    date    val     bucket
id1   d1      1         1
id2   d1      2         1
id3   d1      3         2
id4   d1      4         2
id1   d2      10        1
id2   d2      20        1
id3   d2      30        2
id4   d2      40        2
```

Comment: FYI, to create code blocks, simply indent the lines in the block by four spaces. (And in general, see the `?` at the top right of the edit box for more formatting rules).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it with `transform` is slick, but why not something more basic like

```
tmpf <- function(x) {
   x[[new_column_name_1]] <- myfun(x[[column_name_1]])
   x[[new_column_name_2]] <- myfun(x[[column_name_2]])
   ...
   x
}
ddply(df,"dt",tmpf)
```

Or you can have a vector of column names to modify, or do it on the fly:

```
tmpf <- function(x,cols=c("column_name_1","column_name_2")) {
   newcols <- paste("new",cols,sep="_")
   for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
      x[[newcols[i]]] <- myfun(x[[cols[i]]])
   }
}
```

There's probably something even cleverer with `assign` in the appropriate environment.

If I had a reproducible example I could test this.

Comment: yes, this is what i do currently.  i was trying to do something with assign as you suggest but couldn't get things to work syntactically.  your answer works fine though, thanks!

Comment: Don't see why you need `ddply` - you're doing the same thing to every group! Also see `plyr::rename`

Comment: maybe `myfun` is something like `function(x) x/mean(x)`, so we would have to transform the bits group by group, rather than in one go.  (A reproducible example would settle some of these questions ...)

Comment: i just updated my question.  The basic idea is I have a bunch of dates and for each date I have a bunch of id's and I want to bucket these id's by their value on each date (so each date has a set of buckets 1...N).  If there is a more efficient way of doing this than ddply please let me know.

Comment: the issue with this solution is that I can't modify the data frame from within my function since R passes everything by value; can't find how to pass by reference in R if this exists